# NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer vs CreateTimer - what's the difference?

Tags: xamarin.ios

MonoTouch documentation at http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.Foundation.NSTimer doesn't say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MT Rosetta Stone](http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html)

> CreateScheduledTimer ==> scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval
>
> CreateTimer ==> timerWithTimeInterval

Apple's [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) docs say the difference between the two is that the ScheduledTimer variant is "scheduled on the current run loop in the default mode."

Comment: Does that mean that a non-scheduled timer won't actually fire until added to a run loop? Why would you want to create a timer without adding it to a run loop (IOW when would you use CreateTimer instead of CreateScheduledTimer)?

Comment: This is not entirely clear to me - my assumption is that one creates the timer and immediately starts it, where the other creates a timer that you can then manually start later in your code.